# Content inside toolbar not collapsing/scrolling if content height higher than display

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

If i have such a configuration as shown below, like a custom `View` inside a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with height more than a screen height, i cannot collapse it. 
What for i need to do it? I need to have a content which will scroll up with a `recyclerview` below it. Without parallax or other effect, just scroll.

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresher"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/accent_material_light"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">

       <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/coordinator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">


            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

                    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="1500dp"
                          android:background="@color/green_A100"
                          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                            />
                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

                    />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: What version of the design library are you using? The latest `23.1.0`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake 23.0.1, what's your point?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Support Library 23.1 release blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html):

> You’ll also find that `AppBarLayout` now allows users to start scrolling from within the AppBarLayout rather than only from within your scrollable view

If you'd like to start scrolling from within your `AppBarLayout`/`CollapsingToolbarLayout`, you'll want to update to at least version `23.1.0` of the Design Library.

Comment: oh, thank you. I tried that, but it still cuts my content which height is far more than screen, i think it's another case

Comment: I am already using 23.1.1. this issue still persists. Please help